# Develop Sharepoint 2013 web parts from client using VS 2012

Tags: 2013, development, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, apps-development

How I can develop my visual web parts from my client using VS 2012? When I want to create a sharepoint 2013 project I receive a message that sharepoint server  does not installed on my client.

Is there any way to solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

When a visual webpart is created it has references to sharepoint server object model dlls and for that you need to work in a machine with sharepoint installed.